# Using codehaus 'ObjectMappper' class in GWT application to parse json

Tags: gwt

I want to use `ObjectMapper` class from 'codehaus' library in client side of GWT application. I am getting error `no source code available for ObjectMapper class` .

Any solution for this? Is it not possible to use Java library classes in GWT application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to use Java source code in GWT, but libraries should be adapted. Some libraries just require a [GWT module](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/FAQ_Client.html#What_is_a_GWT_Module?) to indicate that the source code should be transpiled by GWT and others might require some level of adaptation. Concretely, anything related to reflection is not supported in GWT, and Jackson uses a lot of reflection so it is quite difficult to adapt.

**Solution:** You should use an alternative implementation like https://github.com/nmorel/gwt-jackson or https://github.com/DominoKit/gwt-jackson-apt. Or just delegate the coding/decoding of JSON to the native [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) optionally applying the [JsInterop DTO strategy](https://github.com/intendia-oss/autorest/wiki/JsInterop-DTO-strategy) to make the models work in both GWT client side and JRE server side.

Comment: Thanks @Ignacio for 'reflection restriction'. I did this with parsing json string by native function..